# How do I use the __cpp_lib_* feature test macros?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, std

I wanted to use the [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) to check if `std::filesystem` was available, but `__cpp_lib_filesystem` isn't defined even when I know `std::filesystem` is present. For example, the following test program:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    std::cout << "__cpp_lib_filesystem: "
#ifdef __cpp_lib_filesystem
        << __cpp_lib_filesystem
#else
        << "not defined"
#endif
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "__has_include(filesystem): "
#ifndef __has_include
        << "don't have __has_include"
#elif __has_include(<filesystem>)
        << "yes"
#else
        << "no"
#endif
        << std::endl;

}

// also, this compiles:
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::path test;
```

Outputs this with gcc 8.1 (my actual target compiler) and gcc 11.2, with `--std=c++17`:

```
__cpp_lib_filesystem: not defined
__has_include(filesystem): yes
```

[Here it is on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1rndcqr65).

I also tried including `<version>`, but, with GCC 8.1, it's not present:

```
<source>:2:10: fatal error: version: No such file or directory
 #include <version>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Additionally, [the note here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version) says:

> Library feature-test macros - defined in the header <version> (C++20)

Which, unless I'm misinterpreting, means the library feature test macros aren't in `<version>` until C++20, which doesn't apply to C++17 (although I'm not really clear if it means the *header* is the C++20 feature, or if the *macros* are the C++20 feature).

Now, in this particular case, I know I can test for it by doing:

```c++
#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<filesystem>)
    // ...
#else
    // ...
#endif
```

That'll work here because filesystem was officially added in C++17 and `__has_include` has been around since C++17 (or maybe earlier, I dunno) as well -- i.e. there shouldn't be a situation where `__has_include` isn't available but `std::filesystem` is. So that's fine.

However, my question is about `__cpp_lib_filesystem`: Why isn't it defined in the above test? What did I miss / how do I use it?

Comment: You appear to be missing `#include <version>`.  The `__cpp_lib_filesystem` is defined if you include `<version>` or `<filesystem>`.

Comment: @Eljay I actually tried that; but GCC 8.1 doesn't have `<version>`, and also the note on cppreference states that the lib feature macros weren't added to `<version>` until C++20. I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: iirc, the feature flags were introduced with C++11, and in part are intended for feature testing because many compilers roll out feature compliance piecemeal over time, until they declare feature complete (modulo bugs).

Comment: I found this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646 -- was hopeful but, `#include <ciso646>` didn't get the macro defined either. I may upgrade this with a [tag:language-lawyer] bat signal if things get dire, .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to use the `__cpp_lib_XXX` macros:

1. Actually include the corresponding header: https://godbolt.org/z/xo68acnrz

   - And the given library also need to support such feature with the given C++ version

     - e.g., `__cpp_lib_constexpr_vector` will not be defined under C++17 even if `<vector>` was included.
2. Uses C++20, and include the `<version>` header.

Comment: I see; so for C++17,  it comes down to just using `__has_include` first, including the file, and then testing any corresponding `__cpp_lib_*` as a confirmation for a specific feature?

Comment: @JasonC That is correct

Comment: Excellent; thank you for your answer.